# Does solr use cosine similarity?

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine

I have written a small search engine as my weekly project. It is based upon cosine similarity between query vector and document vector. Vector is calculate using of tf-idf sores of tokens.
I have come to know about Apache Solr which is a full text search engine. My question is does solr use cosine similarity internally when rank search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Solr (which runs on top of Lucene) does use Cosine similarity. From the Lucene documentation:

> VSM score of document d for query q is the Cosine Similarity of the
>   weighted query vectors V(q) and V(d)
>
> cosine-similarity(q,d)   =    V(q) · V(d) / |V(q)| |V(d)|

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

Answer (score 7):

No.  Solr uses something *similar* to cosine similarity, but not quite the same - there are some key differences.

If you visit that same link (https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) and scroll further down, you will see "Lucene Conceptual Scoring Formula" and "Lucene Practical Scoring Formula" that give more details.

Ignoring any index/query-time boosts, the following are some key differences:

**1. Different document normalization factor**

Instead of normalizing each document by the Euclidean norm of its tf-idf vector, it uses "doc-len-norm".  For the default similarity measure (DefaultSimilairty) this is just 1/sqrt(number of terms in the doc) which basically equals 1/sqrt(sum(tf)) - i.e., where tf is the sum of the term counts in the doc - no squaring as with the Euclidean norm and the idf for each term is left out.  Furthermore this value is rounded to a byte to save space.  This will most often come out to a different value than the normalization factor as used for cosine similarity.

**2. Extra "coord" boost**

There is also an extra value multiplied onto the score equal to:
   the number of query terms matched in the document / the total number of terms in the query.

This gives an extra boost for fields (documents) matching more of the query terms, and may be of questionable value.  This essentially is multiplying the tf-idf vector score with another inner product - the inner product of these vectors converted to boolean vectors (0 if it does not have the given term, 1 if it does) with the query vector only normalized by its Euclidean norm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for actual vector similarity in Solr, there are two approaches:
1) use delimited payloads. There are a few plugins that implement this already, like https://github.com/moshebla/solr-vector-scoring and https://github.com/saaay71/solr-vector-scoring

2) use streaming expressions, which comes out of the box: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/vector-math.html

The latter is slower, but more flexible.